# how can i check 4 checkboxes together each having a datagrid view with binded data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 4 checkboxes.while,checking 1 at a time,I m getting its corresponding datagrid view.I want to get the total from each of the datagrid view and store it in a textbox.
Then i want to display the sum from all the datagrid view.Now i am getting only value from one datagrid view.how can i do this?

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 || e.ColumnIndex == 3)
            {
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value);


                dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value = a * b;
               // sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    sum += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                }
               // textBox2.Text = sum.ToString();


            }
        }
        else if(checkBox2.Checked==true)
        {
             if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 || e.ColumnIndex == 3)
             {
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value);


                dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value = a * b;
                // s = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    s += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                }
             }
        }
        else if (checkBox3.Checked == true)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 || e.ColumnIndex == 3)
            {
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value);


                dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value = a * b;
              //   u = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    u += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                }
            }
        }
        else if(checkBox4.Checked==true)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 || e.ColumnIndex == 3)
            {
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
                int b = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value);


                dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value = a * b;
                // m = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    m += Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're only executing the first block of code where the if-expression evaluates to true.
Remove the else in the other blocks so that the expression can be evaluated too.
An else-block is only executed when the if-block evaluates to false.

```
If (checkBox1.Checked)
{
     // Your stuff
}
If (checkBox2.Checked)
{
     // Your stuff
}
If (checkBox3.Checked)
{
     // Your stuff
}
If (checkBox3.Checked)
{
     // Your stuff
}
```

Note that you can write the check a bit shorter. You can ommit the `= true` part.

**EDIT**

When doing the above, you will indeed execute `Your stuff`everytime your checkbox is unchecked and checked again.

There are 2 possibilities to accompllish the desired behaviour:

*Option 1:* Remove the columns when the box is unchecked:

```
If (checkBox1.Checked)
{
     // Add columns
}
else
{
    // Remove columns
}

If (checkBox2.Checked)
{
   // Add columns
}
else
{
  // Remove columns
}
```

*Option 2:* Check whether the columns exist or not. This will keep the columns in place, even when the checkbox is unchecked, but will not add new ones, if they already exist.

```
If (checkBox1.Checked) && ( columns are not present)
{
     // Add columns
}

If (checkBox2.Checked) && ( columns are not present)
{
   // Add comlumns
}
```

In both cases you'll get a maximum of 2 other columns.

Comment: how can i insert two columns each time when i check my checkbox?when i check each check box,i am getting two columns in each check.how can i omit that?

Comment: Updated my answer. If I understand your question correctly, I'll recommend option 1.